# Find values in greater then 10 and find the index in multidimensional array (Scala)

Tags: python, scala

I am learning Scala, and I would like to do manipulation on multidimensional array . Could someone please indicate if its possible to do something like the below (Python/NumPy code) in Scala?

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 10, 20], [20, 30, 40]])

print("Values bigger than 10 =", x[x>10])

print("Indices ", np.nonzero(x > 10))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far? Any error you don't understand?

Comment: To get exactly that you would need to mix some `zipWithIndex` + `map` + `filter` calls. To be honest, **numpy** is pretty powerful, especially for multidimensional arrays. however, also being honest, I don't see much point in doing exactly what you asked, you would then need to use those indexes to something else which could probably be inlined in the maps from above simplifying the logic.

Comment: Do you want to write it from scratch, or do you want to use something roughly resembling `numpy`, such as [numsca](https://index.scala-lang.org/botkop/numsca)?

Comment: I want to get all of the elements and their indices from this matrix which are < 40

scala> matrix.show
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|_c5|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 30|  0| 13| 21| 25| 15|
| 55| 47| 26| 54| 44|  3|
| 21| 19| 23| 47| 29| 13|
| 52| 50| 44| 14| 21| 24|
| 10| 37|  0| 22| 17| 58|
| 36| 55| 48| 27| 13| 35|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Comment: @Marto, did you see the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't generic in the dimensionality of the array like numpy probably is (only works for 2-dimensions), but accomplishes specifically what's in your question:

```scala
val x = List(List(0, 10, 20), List(20, 30, 40))

def vals(xs: List[List[Int]])(p: Int => Boolean): List[Int] =
    for {
    row <- xs
    v <- row if p(v)
  } yield v

def indices(xs: List[List[Int]])(p: Int => Boolean): List[(Int, Int)] =
    for {
    (row, r) <- xs.zipWithIndex
    (v, c) <- row.zipWithIndex if p(v)
  } yield (r, c)

vals(x)(_ > 10) // List(20, 20, 30, 40)
indices(x)(_ > 10) // List((0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2))
```

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4TajfVmiRwyN8fp1wTeg6Q

UPDATE:

Here's another scastie with a (rough) example on how to make this more generic both in terms of the number of dimensions as well as the element types:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Y1MrZCvHQ2iTwiBrUraiAw

It mimics numpy's syntax a bit more closely at the cost of some type-safety. Also, it uses Scala 3, in particular it relies on the ability to grow tuples dynamically